# c# Android - BluetoothServerSocket.Accept gives no result

Tags: c#, android, bluetooth, server, connection

I am trying to listen at incoming Bluetooth connection thanks to this code based on this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html):

```
public void WaitForConnection()
{
    BluetoothServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
    if (adapter == null)
        throw new Exception("No Bluetooth adapter found");
    if (!adapter.IsEnabled)
        throw new Exception("Bluetooth adapter is not enabled");

    // Create a new listening server socket
    try
    {
        serverSocket = adapter.ListenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("MindCam", UUID.FromString(Ev3UUID));
    }
    catch (Java.IO.IOException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error listening connection: " + e.Message);
    }

    Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                _socket = serverSocket.Accept();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Socket's accept() method failed");
                break;
            }

            if (_socket != null)
            {
                // A connection was accepted.
                serverSocket.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted");
                break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I call this method at the beginning of an activity. I debug that, and it seems that the code is executed until "serverSocket.Accept()", and even if it is not awaited, the code is no more executed. Afterwards, even when I attempt to make a connection from a Bluetooth device (a Mindstorms brick) to the Android device, it is not detected and this thread doesn't continue...

Why doesn't this work ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Accept` is a locking function, it will stop the execution until a proper connection is received, that's the expected behavior. Also, if the name or the UUID is not the correct one then no device will connect never.

Comment: Thanks, OK, I thought only "awaited" functions can result in this behaviour... The UUID is the same as the one I used to make the connection from the smartphone to the Bluetooth device, and this connection works, so I think it is the good one. And about the name, which one do I have to use ? It is written in the documentation: "The name is arbitrary and can simply be your application name."